# PHP return a certain amount of code based on a value

Tags: php

I am trying to create a visual representation of a user rating from 1 to 5 (including .5 values) in the form of stars and half-stars.  I have already created the array of user ratings from the MySQL database, I have averaged those values to create an average user rating in the form of a number.  What I would like to do is take this value..

```
$averageuserrating
```

And if that value is "1", then return this code once

```
 echo '<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" />';
```

If $averageuserrating is 1.5, then this code will be returned

```
<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" /><img src="images/halfstar.png" class="ratingstar" />
```

And so on... Is there a way to do this without 10 nested if statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by something like this:

```
$fullStar = '<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" />';
$halfStar = '<img src="images/halfstar.png" class="ratingstar" />';

$rating = 1.5;

while($rating > 0){
    if($rating >= 1){
        echo $fullStar;
        $rating = $rating - 1;
        continue;
    }

    if($rating >= 0.5){
        echo $halfStar;
        $rating = $rating - 0.5;
    }
}
```

On a side note, this is not the best way to display a rating system.

Comment: What would you suggest as the best way to display a rating system?

Comment: By using CSS and sprites. `<div class="stars stars-<?php echo str_replace('.', '-', $rating);?>"></div>` and then styling .stars, .stars-1, .stars-1-5 etc. accordingly.

Comment: That was genius.  I knew there had to be a better more succinct way to do it than what I was trying.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem mate. Please choose an answer when you feel that you question has been answered properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= floor($averageuserrating); $i++)
    echo '<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" />';
if($averageuserrating > floor($averageuserrating))
    echo '<img src="images/halfstar.png" class="ratingstar" />';
```

Note: If you have averages not only incremented by 0.5, but for example you can get 1.4:
Change the second condition to:

```
if($averageuserrating >= (floor($averageuserrating) + 0.5))
```

Comment: +1 but note that if the average is `1.00000001` this will show 1.5 stars - perhaps the 2nd line condition should be `floor($averageuserrating)+1.5` ?

Comment: He said "from 1 to 5 (including .5 values)", so there are just values: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 and so...

Comment: But ok.. I've added a note.

Comment: We read that differently - perhaps the OP can clarify. I'd be surprised if an average was always a round number...

Comment: Yes, Blaskovic is right.  Average ratings are rounded to the nearest .5 value in order to keep it simple for the end user.

Comment: I'm getting this error with your code...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INC, expecting ')' in

Comment: I am sorry. There is missing '$' in the for() cycle for the last 'i' variable.. Code fixed :) Try it!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `str_repeat` function and a bit mathematics.

```
$full_star = '<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" />';
$half_star = '<img src="images/halfstar.png" class="ratingstar" />';

echo str_repeat( $full_star, floor($averageuserrating) );
if(! is_int($averageuserrating) ){
    echo $half_star;
}
```

I think it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use switch statement.

```
switch($value){
case "1";
echo '<img src="images/star1.png" class="ratingstar" />';
break; 
case "1";
echo '<img src="images/star2.png" class="ratingstar" />';
break;

so on and so forth.. 

}
```

Comment: I am sure someone can post better alternatives though

Comment: Just 2 points - firstly, your 2nd case element is checking for `1` too. Secondly, this only works if the average is a whole number - which averages usually aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a possible solution:

```
$numWholeStars = (int)$averageuserrating;

$numHalfStars = $averageuserrating - (int)$averageuserrating;

for($i = 0; $i < $numWholeStars; $i++) {
    echo '<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" />';
}

if($numHalfStars != 0) {
    echo '<img src="images/halfstar.png" class="ratingstar" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to re-factor your underlying code to a) gather all the ratings b) show how many stars the rating should display. Firstly see  [php math - modulus](https://www.php.net/operators.arithmetic)

```
get_user_ratings($user="bob")
{
    15 - the user ratings should/could be in 1 place (int)users.total_ratings
    // lets say there are 15 records similar to the one below
    jim, 1, bob 
    ...
    mary, 1.5, bob
    
    // calculate the average of all votes
    ...
    ...
    /* If your rating system offers the chance to rate a user 1.5 stars
     use modulus to check if the rating needs half stars */
    $stars = "";
    if( $averageuserrating % 1 == 0)
    {
        for(
            i=0;
            i<$averageuserrating-1; 
           $i++;$stars .= '<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" />'; 
        )
        return $stars;
    }
    else
    {
        for(
            i=0;
            i<$averageuserrating-1; 
            $i++;$stars .='<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" />' 
        )
        $stars .= '<img src="images/halfstar.png" class="ratingstar" />'; 
        return $stars;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fullstar = '<img src="images/star.png" class="ratingstar" />';
$halfstar = '<img src="images/halfstar.png" class="ratingstar" />';

$value=2.5;//some rating

$number = number_format ( $value, 1 );
$fs = floor ( $number );  //full stars
$hs=(($value*10)%10)/5;   //half stars


while($fs>0)
{
echo $fullstar;
$fs=$fs-1;
}

if($hs==1)
echo $halfstar;
```